# How to enrich result list from FirebaseListObservable with FirebaseObjectObservables

Tags: firebase, rxjs, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I have a FirebaseListObservable with IDs and I want to look them up using FirebaseObjectObservable and create a Array of the result, but I don't really understand how to do it.

```
  this.af.database.list('/favourites/'+ this.userId)
  .flatMap(favouriteId => {
    return this.af.database.object('/dhs/en/'+favouriteId.$value)
  })
  .subscribe(favourite => {
    console.log("favourite", favourite);
  });
```

This doesn't work because favouriteId.$value is undefined. What is the right way to do this?

This is a related question: [How to merge an observable that is a property of another observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548444/how-to-merge-an-observable-that-is-a-property-of-another-observable)

EDIT: I have created an ugly temporary solution

```
  getAllFavourites(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      var resArray = [];
      this.af.database.list('/favourites/'+ this.userId)
      .subscribe(favouriteArray => {
        favouriteArray.forEach((favouriteId) => {
          this.secretProvider.getDay(favouriteId.$value)`
          .subscribe(favourite => {
            resArray.push(favourite);
            observer.next(resArray);
          });
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

Obviously this is not the purpose of observables and in addition the resulting observable array is not updated correctly when for example a `favourite ID` is removed from `this.af.database.list('/favourites/'+ this.userId)`.

UPDATE: I have found a better solution following this thread: [How to move FirebaseObjectObservable into a FirebaseListObservable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897543/how-to-move-firebaseobjectobservable-into-a-firebaselistobservable?rq=1)

```
getAllFavourites(): Observable<any> {
      return this.af.database.list('/favourites/'+ this.userId)
      .map((favourites)=>{
        return favourites.map((favourite) => {
          favourite = this.secretProvider.getDay(favourite.$value)
          return favourite;
        })
      });
  }
```

(and in the HTML using a nested async varibale as described in the other thread)

I still think there must be a better solution though. Something using mergeMap or similar, and avoiding the nested asyncs.